# log4net store ADO.NET call

Tags: log4net

I'm new in using log4net . Now I need to create a window form app , and it can log all ADO.net call from my website . it means save all what parameter and call I'm passing to DB !

Thanks all !

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried so far, what is the actual problem where you do not know where to go on. Do you have propblems with logging api or logging configuration or does your [Aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) logging aspect not work or ...? Themore specific your question is the more likely you will get an answer and the less likeliy your question will be closed as beeing to broad.

Comment: hi k3b , what all I need is : whenever my website call any ado.net to database , this window app will show it , I want to use log4net ! But I don't really know how to do it ! I really need your advice ! Thanks !